# Upper limit for the weight in "Table Rates" shipping method

Tags: magento-2.1, table-rates

In Magento 2.1. How can I set upper limit for the weight when using "Table Rates" shipping method?

If the highest weight I can ship is 7 KG, having that record as the highest in my Tables Rates means that any item ( or items total) weight is 7 KG will cost X amount for shipping, AND ALSO higher than that, for example 90 KG will cost the same X amount for shipping! ... how can I put limit for that?!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to make items over a certain weight cost an astronomical amount to ship, but this is a very messy and unprofessional looking workaround. I have the same issue at the moment on my 2.1 store.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the free MatrixRate Table Rate Shipping extension: https://marketplace.magento.com/webshopapps-module-matrixrate.html

It gives you some more options than the default table rates but these options are covering a lot more use cases. Besides that the extension is used just like the built in table rates.

In your case I would use its weight vs destination setting which will allow you to upload a CSV with the following fields:

```
Country,Region/State,City,"Zip/Postal Code From","Zip/Postal Code To",Weight>,Weight<=,"Shipping Price","Shipping Method"
```

You now can state an exact weight range with not only a price but also a custom "Shipping Method" names. Customers see all prices/method names depending on their total cart weight in a list. Personally I'd advice to hide `.table-checkout-shipping-method .col-carrier` via CSS as this will always show the generic name you gave the MatrixRate Table Rate option in the admin backend and my confuse customers if you make use of the "Shipping Method" field in the CSV.

I just installed this module in 2.1.8 installation and for me it worked out of the box (I did a manual installation).